# Scope returning all but the X most recent records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to come up with a scope that returns all the records but the X most recent ones.

All the samples I have seen around return either the X more recent records or the X oldest ones.

Any ideas about how to achieve what I need with a `SQLite` DB?

I haven't posted any code because I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `offset`:

```
scope.order(created_at: :desc).offset(x)
```

It generates SQL query similar to:

```
select your_table.* from your_table order by your_table.created_at desc offset x;
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the SQL generated by the query you suggested? Thanks.

Comment: @Sig I posted not the exact output SQL query, but the one similar enough.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't able to use the `offset` method provided by Rails because my Rails is very old. However, it pointed me in the right direction.